# create your own custom cellfun function

Tags: matlab

I have a cell array called myCellArray. It is of size 1 x 1500. Snap shot below (please note the column numbers are not part of myCellArray was just to hopefully help highlight the answer vector I wanted returned).

```
1    2   3   4   5   6  7  8  9   10  11  12 13

ABC  []  DEF DEF DEF [] [] [] ABC ABC ABC [] DEF
```

I want to use cellfun to call a custom function that will take a parameter like 'ABC' then for it to return a vector where ABC is present so the answer should look like below,

```
[1 9 10 11]
```

How do you go about creating a custom function for cellfun?

Comment: Should the search be in the two rows, or only in the second?

Comment: sorry the row with the numbers is not actually part of myCellArray. It was just so you could easily see how I got the answer. I'll update my post

Comment: I gave a general answer assuming you had several rows, but it'll work too with just one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give the indices of columns that contain the desired string (in any row):

```
c = {1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13
    'ABC' [] 'DEF' 'DEF' 'DEF' [] [] [] 'ABC' 'ABC' 'ABC' [] 'DEF'};
indices = find(any(strcmp('ABC', c), 1));
```

The key is to note that the [`strcmp`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcmp.html) function

- works for cell arrays, taking the contents of each cell in turn;
- gives `false` if any of its inputs is not a string.

If you have only one row, you can remove `any(...,1)` (although the general answer will also work):

```
c = {'ABC' [] 'DEF' 'DEF' 'DEF' [] [] [] 'ABC' 'ABC' 'ABC' [] 'DEF'};
indices = find(strcmp('ABC', c));
```